# Spring Integration poller sometimes runs once then stops

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following annotation-based configuration in a Spring Integration app:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller(@Value("${poll-interval}") int pollInterval) {
    return Pollers.fixedRate(pollInterval).maxMessagesPerPoll(1).get();
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "httpRequestChannel", poller = @Poller(PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER),
    autoStartup = "${auto-start:true}")
public MessageSource<String> httpRequestTrigger() {
    Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
        "#{@timeService.getLastQueryTime()}",
        new TemplateParserContext("#{", "}"));
    return new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageSource<>(expression, String.class);
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("httpRequestChannel")
public MessageChannel httpRequestChannel() {
    return new RendezvousChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "httpRequestChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate="100"))
public MessageHandler httpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
    URI backendURI,
    @Qualifier("httpReplyChannel") MessageChannel httpReplyChannel,
    RestTemplate restTemplate,
    @Qualifier("filterExpression") Expression filterExpression
) {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler messageHandler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
        backendURI.toString() + "?filter={filter}", restTemplate);
    messageHandler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    messageHandler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
    messageHandler.setOutputChannel(httpReplyChannel);
    messageHandler.setExpectReply(true);
    messageHandler.setSendTimeout(1000);
    Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExpressions = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariableExpressions.put("filter", filterExpression);
    messageHandler.setUriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExpressions);
    return messageHandler;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("httpReplyChannel")
public MessageChannel httpReplyChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

In my `application.properties` file, `auto-start` is set to `true` and `poll-interval` is set to 2000.

Sometimes when starting up the application, the poller will work as expected, firing every `poll-interval` milliseconds. However, just as often, when starting up, the poller will fire once and never fire again. Is there an error in my configuration? How do I get the poller to consistently work?

**EDIT:** I took a thread dump when the poller hanged:

```
"task-scheduler-1@4820" prio=5 tid=0x13 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
      at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
      at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.put(SynchronousQueue.java:877)
      at org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.doSend(QueueChannel.java:93)
      at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
      at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
      at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
      at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
      at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:210)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
      at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
      at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
      at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
      at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
      at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8081-ClientPoller-1@5021" daemon prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(EPollArrayWrapper.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
      - locked <0x13b0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
      - locked <0x13b1> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
      - locked <0x13b2> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:790)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8081-ClientPoller-0@5017" daemon prio=5 tid=0x17 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(EPollArrayWrapper.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
      - locked <0x13b3> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
      - locked <0x13b4> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
      - locked <0x13b5> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:790)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1@5010" daemon prio=5 tid=0x16 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(EPollArrayWrapper.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
      at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
      - locked <0x13b6> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
      - locked <0x13b7> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
      - locked <0x13b8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
      at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.run(NioBlockingSelector.java:339)

"task-scheduler-3@4847" prio=5 tid=0x15 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8081-Acceptor-0@5022" daemon prio=5 tid=0x19 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
      at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
      - locked <0x13af> (a java.lang.Object)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:456)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"task-scheduler-2@4837" prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
      at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
      - locked <0x13b9> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
      - locked <0x13ba> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
      at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
      at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:84)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
      at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
      at org.howdoevenexist.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.java:24)
      at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
      at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
      at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:516)
      at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382)
      at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
      at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
      at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
      at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
      at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
      at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
      at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
      at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-nio-8081-AsyncTimeout@5025" daemon prio=5 tid=0x1a nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AsyncTimeout.run(AbstractProtocol.java:1137)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"container-0@4216" prio=5 tid=0x12 nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
      at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer$1.run(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:166)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]@4204" daemon prio=5 tid=0x11 nid=NA sleeping
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
      at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-1)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1339)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Finalizer@5037" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler@5038" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"DestroyJavaVM@5035" prio=5 tid=0x1c nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher@5036" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: Are you using the `taskScheduler` bean elsewhere in your app? Typically, such issues are caused by thread starvation in the scheduler (it only has 10 threads by default). Best way to debug is to take a thread dump when you experience the issue to see what the scheduler threads are doing.

Comment: There are a large number of other channels, including asynchronous queue channels, so I suspect you are right. I will increase the number of threads on the scheduler and see what that does.

Comment: Just got a thread dump after the poller stalled. Two task scheduler threads are waiting, one is runnable and apparently stuck in the middle of making an http request.

Comment: Please paste the thread dump into your question.

Comment: You have a bounded queue channel (`httpRequestChannel` ?) as the first channel after the poller - it is highly unusual to do that. The queue in the channel is full; hence polling is suspended until space is made there. We need to figure out the issue in your comment below `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler to anything but QueueChannel `. Can you add the message handler (and channel) configuration?

Comment: I had previously been using a `QueueChannel` but the asynchronous queue was causing severe performance problems as the application ran (after an hour or two of running, what was supposed to take 2 seconds would take 10 minutes or more, which was unacceptable).

Comment: `RendezvousChannel` is a "special" `QueueChannel`. You don't need a queue channel there at all - use a `DirectChannel`, remove the `@Poller` from the `@ServiceActivator` and the HTTP request will run directly on the poller thread so it will naturally throttle the polls based on its speed. But, the entire problem seems to be a slow HTTP request; switching to a direct channel won't help that - it will perform similar to the rendezvous channel.

Comment: Tried using a `DirectChannel`. Seeing similar results. There's one task scheduler thread, and it's hanging at `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)`

Comment: Right - so the root cause is your HTTP service.

Comment: Great, so is there a way to prevent the entire application hanging when a single request hangs?

Comment: You can set  a timeout on the outgoing HttpClient object. If you want to run concurrent requests, you can use a bounded `TaskExecutor` on the poller - perhaps a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a queue size and a CALLER_RUNS or ABORT policy (for when the task queue is full).

Comment: Do I have to do anything other than set timeout on the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` to add a timeout to the outgoing `HttpClient`?

Comment: There are two timeouts `setConnectTimeout()` and `setReadTimeout()`.

Comment: I need to restart the app a couple dozen more times to be absolutely sure, but setting connect and read timeout seems to have eliminated the problem.

Comment: The app now logs a `SocketTimeoutException` and keeps going after a backend timeout, which is acceptable while we work on fixing the problem with the backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Configuring the Task Scheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler) bean - it only has 10 threads by default.

With queue channels in the mix, the threads are suspended for the `receiveTimeout` (1 second by default). If you have a lot of queue channels you can experience thread starvation.

As an aside, you generally don't need lots of queue channels; typically a single thread handoff is enough in a flow.

Comment: There are actually only two queue channels; most of the other channels are set to publish/subscribe. I was having issues setting the output channel on my HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler to anything but QueueChannel but that is perhaps a question for another time.

Comment: In any event, increasing the number of threads available to the task scheduler appears to have fixed my problem nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that that fix only solved the problem sometimes. Even after increasing the number of threads to much larger than I should need (e.g. 100 threads), the poller still sometimes fails to run more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Gary Russell helped me out in the comments so I thought I'd post what turned out to be the solution as an answer in case anyone has the same issue. The issue was not with the poller at all, but with the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`. The stacktrace shows the `task-scheduler-2` thread hanging in the following state:

```
"task-scheduler-2@4837" prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java:-1)
```

This indicated that the request to the backend was hanging. There was no timeout set on the `RestTemplate` used by the message handler, so the thread would wait forever for a request that would never come, which caused the entire application to appear as though it had stopped. My solution was to add the following `ClientHttpRequestFactory` to the `RestTemplate` bean:

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(500);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(500);
    return factory;
}
```

Setting a nonempty read and connect timeout causes the application to log an exception when the backend times out, after which the application continues running as normal. Many thanks to Gary Russell for helping me figure out this perplexing issue.